# How to handle a web service response with multiple namespace VBA SoapClient30

Tags: vba, excel, soap-client

I have a problem when handling an web service response with multiple namespaces using VBA Excel and SoapClient30.

Type Mapper:

```
Dim str_WSML As String
str_WSML = "<servicemapping>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<service name='EmployeeService'>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<using PROGID='MSSOAP.GenericCustomTypeMapper30' cachable='0' ID='GCTM'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<types>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<type name='OperationContext' targetNamespace='http://connectivity.service.ews.mincom.com' uses='GCTM' targetClassName='struct_OperationContext'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<type name='WarningMessageDTO' targetNamespace='http://ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com' uses='GCTM' targetClassName='struct_WarningMessageDTO'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<type name='EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyCollectionDTO' targetNamespace='http://employee.ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com'  uses='GCTM' targetClassName='struct_EmployeeServiceRetri'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<type name='EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyDTO' targetNamespace='http://employee.ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com' uses='GCTM' targetClassName='struct_EmployeeServiceRetri1'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<type name='EmployeeServiceRetrieveRequestDTO' targetNamespace='http://employee.ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com' uses='GCTM' targetClassName='struct_EmployeeServiceRetri12'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "<type name='EmployeeServiceRetrieveRequiredAttributesDTO' targetNamespace='http://employee.ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com' uses='GCTM' targetClassName='struct_EmployeeServiceRetri123'/>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "</types>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "</service>"
str_WSML = str_WSML & "</servicemapping>"
```

The class struct_EmployeeServiceRetri (EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyCollectionDTO) contains the following properties:

```
Public replyElements As Variant
Public collectionRestartPoint As String
```

The response of the web service is

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:retrieveResponse
            xmlns:ns1="http://employee.ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com">
            <ns1:out>
                <ns2:collectionRestartPoint xmlns:ns2="http://ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com">
                     adfsdfsdfsdfASFASDASD
                </ns2:collectionRestartPoint>
                <ns1:replyElements>
                    <ns1:EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyDTO> .... (Here are attributes) </ns1:EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyDTO>
                </ns1:replyElements>
            </ns1:out>
        </ns1:retrieveResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Finally when I run the web service method I get this error

> Generic Custom Type Mapper:Element ns2:collectionRestartPoint can not
>   be found in type definition of
>   EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyCollectionDTO

But when the response of the web service is like this (Without ns2:collectionRestartPoint) ... Works fine

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:retrieveResponse
            xmlns:ns1="http://employee.ellipse.enterpriseservice.mincom.com">
            <ns1:out>
                <ns1:replyElements>
                    <ns1:EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyDTO> .... (Here are attributes) </ns1:EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyDTO>
                </ns1:replyElements>
            </ns1:out>
        </ns1:retrieveResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: No clue whether the client will be able correcting this but it definitely is the fault of the responding web service which declares `xmlns:ns1` properly but lacks the declaration of `xmlns:ns2`. So garbage in - garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

The Employee service is probably one of the most widely used in Ellipse. I find it hard to believe that it would be at fault. I have never used ellipse web services using VBA however, looking at an example that is provided by ABB as part of their documentation all I can think of is that your class for EmployeeServiceRetrieveReplyCollectionDTO may not have a member for collectionRestartPoint.

I.e. Your "struct_EmployeeServiceRetri" should have the following:

Public collectionRestartPoint As String

Public replyElements As Variant

Comment: my apologies. i only just noticed that in your earlier post that you do have both attributes in struct_EmployeeServiceRetri. Other than reorganizing them, i have no other suggestions.